# Auth login not working cakephp 2.5.7 in Server

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

> Hi, Everyone cakephp login works in my localhost, but it doesn't works in
>   web server. 
>       My localhost server php version 5.5 and mysql server 5.6.
>       My web server version 5.2.17 and mysql server 5.1.61-rel13.2-log
>
> Below is my controller code.

### **UsersController.php**

```
 public function login(){
    $this->layout='userlogin';   
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
         if ($this->Auth->login()) 
            {   
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }else{
              $this->request->data=array();
            return  $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, try again','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-danger'),'logerr');
            }
    }
 }
```

### AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
    'RequestHandler','Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'UserDashboard'),
        'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
    )
 );
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are Security.salt and Security.cipherSeed same on local and remote host?   Are the password field has sufficient length to store hashed password?

Comment: Yes, Security.salt and Security.chiperSeed are same for both local and remote host. also we have used sha1 encryption method for password.

Comment: You  mean your code works on local but not on development server ? Please try enable debug -> to 1 ,and check for warnings. If nothing found , try switching debug -> 1 to 0 and then again to 1. Also delete cache manually in tmp folder.

Comment: my debug mode value Configure::write('debug', 2);